# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'id' of null

Tags: reactjs, shopify, shopify-app

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJmW6.png)*when i click add to cart. I get this in the terminal. Im stuck. please help. Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'id' of null. when i click add to cart. I get this in the terminal. Im stuck. please help. Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'id' of null
when i click add to cart. I get this in the terminal. Im stuck. please help. Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'id' of null.
PLEASE NOTE HAT I HAD TO CUT SOME OF THE CODE OFF

***Shopcontext.js***

```
class ShopProvider extends Component {

    state = {
        product: {},
        products: [],
        checkout: {},
        isCartOpen: false,
        isMenuOpen: false
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (localStorage.checkout_id) {
            this.fetchCheckout(localStorage.checkout_id)

        } else {
            this.createCheckout()
        } 
    }


    addItemToCheckout = async (variantId, quantity) => {
      const lineItemsToAdd = [
        {
          variantId,
          quantity: parseInt(quantity, 10)
        }
      ]


         const checkout = await client.checkout.addLineItems(this.state.checkout.id, lineItemsToAdd)
          this.setState({ checkout: checkout })
          console.log(checkout);
          this.openCart();
        }

  fetchAllProducts = async () => {
        const products = await client.product.fetchAll();
        this.setState({ products: products });
      };
    

    fetchProductWithHandle = async (handle) => {
        
        const product = await client.product.fetchByHandle(handle)
        this.setState({ product: product})
    }



    render() {
        return (
          <ShopContext.Provider
          value={{
            ...this.state,
            fetchAllProducts: this.fetchAllProducts,
            fetchProductWithHandle: this.fetchProductWithHandle,
            addItemToCheckout: this.addItemToCheckout,
            removeLineItem: this.removeLineItem,
            closeCart: this.closeCart,
            openCart: this.openCart,
            closeMenu: this.closeMenu,
            openMenu: this.openMenu
          }}
          >
            {this.props.children}
          </ShopContext.Provider>
        );
      }
    }
const ShopConsumer = ShopContext.Consumer

export { ShopConsumer, ShopContext };

export default ShopProvider



**Product page**


const ProductPage = () => {

    const { handle } = useParams();


    const { fetchProductWithHandle, addItemToCheckout, product } = useContext(ShopContext)

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchProductWithHandle(handle)
    }, [fetchProductWithHandle, handle])
    
    if (!product.title) return <div>Loading....</div>
        return (
            <Box>
                
                        <Button
                            onClick={() => addItemToCheckout(product.variants[0].id, 1)}
                        >
                            Add To Cart 
                        </Button>
                    
            </Box>
        )
    }

export default ProductPage;*
```

Comment: You should also include the context part, where product is coming from. 
Try `console.log(product)` and check what you have in the browser console (take a screenshot and include it in your question). Most likely the data is being used in the wrong way

Comment: Yes. 
  fetchAllProducts = async () => {
        const products = await client.product.fetchAll();
        this.setState({ products: products });
      };
    

    fetchProductWithHandle = async (handle) => {
        
        const product = await client.product.fetchByHandle(handle)
        this.setState({ product: product})
    }

Comment: Are you seeing the products after fetching them? console.log(products) inside the fetchAllProducts function and check if you are actually getting the data

Comment: you are not getting variants array in product object make sure you are getting the variants array in product object. try logging the product object in console to check what you are getting.

Comment: Yes Alex. i am getting the products after fetching them, no problem with that. I am just not able to add to cart

Comment: Variant array? What exactly do you mean @IhtishamTanveer? I have logged it and i dont understand what you mean

Comment: @AlexYepes i have added a screen shot of what the console shows in the question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

this is a general answer for this problem hope someone can benefit from it
so the problem when you encounter the error: Cannot read property '****' of null is that your trying to mape into a null object so first try to look to object and verify way it is null and verify that object container id or whatever it is,
sometimes the object takes time to render so that's why it gives this problem so how a avoid it is adding condition when I use the element like `{object.id&&(<div>....</div)}`
hope this answer can help someone :)